# ¿Cómo recuperar HiddenField en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Dentro de mi programa.aspx tengo definido un HiddenField que uso para ocultar o mostrar una grilla:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hf_statusGrilla" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
```

Luego, dentro del CodeBehind, le asigno el valor que va a tener:

```
hf_statusGrilla.Value = "Ocultar";
```

Luego de asignar el valor lo que hago es obtenerlo mediante un JavaScript, pero este JavaScript siempre me devuelve el error "hf_statusGrilla no está definido".

Así obtengo el valor de hf_statusGrilla desde el JavaScript:

```
var estado = document.getElementById('hf_statusGrilla').value;
```

¿Alguien sabe qué puede estar pasando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obtener el id de un elemento debes de utilizar la propiedad [`ClientId`](https://www.google.com.do/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiD--KPidTUAhWDyyYKHRBlCAgQFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.web.ui.control.clientid(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNH5wTXrSpcuY8zHBgGf8sJkkrBiEA&cad=rjt) del control:

```
var estado = document.getElementById('<%= hf_statusGrilla.ClientID %>').value;
```